# Where is the .minecraft folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I was watching a video and there was this step where you had to find your resource folder and I tried finding the folder but I couldn't.
I clicked the Windows key and r and it brought me to this run thing. Then I typed %appdata%.minecraft. I tried to find the folder from there but I couldn't

I'm on a Windows 10 computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you need to only type `%appdata%` and not `%appdata%.minecraft`.

Comment: I'm afraid that is incorrect. The AppData shortcut requires `%` signs on both sides.

Comment: sorry, typo! fixed it

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo. But there is a way to type the Minecraft folder path directly, rather than clicking on the `.minecraft` folder from the appdata folder.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14, yeah Ik you can just do `%appdata%/.minecraft/` to do it directly but i thought this was simpler